# MacBook Pro won't boot anymore after a fall

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have an old MacBook Pro (late 2006) and he won't boot anymore. He fell down the table and ever since, he's not working anymore. When I try to boot him, the hard drive and the fans starts spinning, but after a few seconds everything is shut down with a "loud" click.

Here is what I've tried:

- Reinsert the Ram
- Replacing the RAM with new ones
- Used the RAM in another Mac, works just fine
- Unchained the hard drive and used an other one
- Used the hard drive in another Mac and PC, works just fine
- Resetting everything you can (PRAM, SMC,...)

Calling Apple Support won't do much since the warranty has expired like 4 years ago.

What I'm afraid of, is a broken motherboard or graphic card (which I don't know how to test this). What are you thinking of when you read this story and what do you think I can do about it?

Comment: It sounds to me like your machine may be hosed. I'm sorry that happened to you. Hopefully you have a complete, recent backup of your computer so you can get another one and get back in business. I dropped a MacBook Pro a while ago but just suffered a broken hard disk, dented case and hurt pride: http://www.richardsnotes.org/archives/2006/12/17/macbook-pro-survives-fall-sort-of/ and the HD replacement: http://www.richardsnotes.org/archives/2006/12/26/macbook-pro-hard-disk-replacement/. I think your situation sounds considerably worse, sorry.

Comment: The hard drive isn't harmed, because it works perfectly in my other Mac (so no data is lost, oef!) but it's just to bad of my "old-school" Mac :)

Comment: A few more things to try, even though they may only confirm what you suspect (or not!):  Press the battery button and see if it shows a charge.  Boot with battery alone; with battery and charger; with battery removed and charger alone.  Try booting to the install DVD; if that works, run the diagnostics.  Try booting into target disk mode (hold 'T' key while booting) and look at the disk from another computer connected by firewire (knowing already that the disk works, this would test cable, connecter & controller). Open the back and look for loose connectors and physical damage.

Comment: Ok,some great suggestions. I'll try them later on this day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you're probably right about the logic board being damaged. Unfortunately, that repair is not inexpensive. For a flat rate depot repair, you're looking at around $1240. For an in store (at an Apple Retail Store), you're looking at a little under $1000.

It looks like you've tried all the troubleshooting steps you can do when it shuts off after a minute.

As the folks in the Apple Store will tell you, you're going to be better off looking at a new machine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info... I was afraid of getting this bad news, but nothing I can do about it! I'll look out for a new MacBook Pro!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do to rescue whatever you can (RAM, harddrive, Bluetooth chips, WiFi antenna,...) and sell them. By so, you have a little start up budget for your new Mac (which you gonna have to buy anyway!)

If you don't know how to get all those things out, you can try one of the tutorials at [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com).